# React - WEBRTC - Peer to Peer - Video call - Doesn't seem to work

Tags: react-native, webrtc, videocall

I have being trying to make a Video call inside a React-Native app. Currently using `react-native-webrtc`, which is the mainstream lib for this kind of project.

I'm pretty new to this, but based on the minimum example of p2p video ([found here](https://github.com/baconcheese113/react-native-webrtc-minimal/blob/master/src/App.js)), i made a code trying to make if work with different networks.
The example creates a connection between one streamer to a receiver, but both on the same page execution, same network, same everything.

In my case i need both users to stream video and receive video, from different networks.
Problem is, i can't find a decent place to read and understand how the negotiation actually works on this scenario.

Code sample:

```
/**
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from '../firebase.config';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
    View,
    SafeAreaView,
    Button,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { RTCPeerConnection, RTCView, mediaDevices } from 'react-native-webrtc';
import store from '../redux/store';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { User } from 'models';
const oUserService = new User().getService(firebase);
const oCurrentReceivedStreamingService = new User().getService(
    firebase,
    store,
    'currentReceivedStreaming',
);

const viewport = Dimensions.get('window');

const Streaming = {
    call: (caller, receiver, localDescription) => {
        return {
            status: 'pending',
            users: {
                caller: {
                    uid: caller.uid,
                    localDescription,
                },
                receiver: {
                    uid: receiver.uid,
                    localDescription: '',
                },
            },
        };
    },
    answer: (receiver, localDescription) => {
        return {
            ...receiver.streaming,
            status: 'ongoing',
            users: {
                ...receiver.streaming.users,
                receiver: {
                    ...receiver.streaming.users.receiver,
                    localDescription,
                },
            },
        };
    },
    close: streaming => {
        return {
            ...streaming,
            status: 'closed',
        };
    },
};

const configuration = {
    iceServers: [
        { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.ekiga.net' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.ideasip.com' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.iptel.org' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.schlund.de' },
        // { url: 'stun:stunserver.org' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.softjoys.com' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.voiparound.com' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.voipbuster.com' },
        // { url: 'stun:stun.voipstunt.com' },
    ],
};

export default function App({ user, receiver, caller, session }) {
    const currentUserStore = useSelector(s => s.currentUserStore);
    const userStreamingStore = useSelector(s => s.userStreamingStore);
    const currentReceivedStreaming = useSelector(
        s => s.currentReceivedStreaming,
    );

    const [localStream, setLocalStream] = React.useState();
    const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = React.useState();
    const [cachedLocalPC, setCachedLocalPC] = React.useState();
    const [cachedRemotePC, setCachedRemotePC] = React.useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        oCurrentReceivedStreamingService.get(caller.uid);
    }, [receiver, caller, user, session]);

    let localPC, remotePC;

    const startLocalStream = async () => {
        const isFront = true;
        const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

        const facing = isFront ? 'front' : 'back';
        const videoSourceId = devices.find(
            device => device.kind === 'videoinput' && device.facing === facing,
        );
        const facingMode = isFront ? 'user' : 'environment';
        const constraints = {
            audio: true,
            video: {
                mandatory: {
                    minWidth: (viewport.height - 100) / 2,
                    minHeight: (viewport.height - 100) / 2,
                    minFrameRate: 30,
                },
                facingMode,
                optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
            },
        };
        const newStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        setLocalStream(newStream);
        return Promise.resolve(newStream);
    };

    const startCall = async () => {
        try {
            let newStream = await startLocalStream();
            oCurrentReceivedStreamingService.get(session.user.uid);

            localPC = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
            remotePC = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

            localPC.onicecandidate = e => {
                try {
                    if (e.candidate) {
                        remotePC.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(`Error adding remotePC iceCandidate: ${err}`);
                }
            };
            remotePC.onicecandidate = e => {
                try {
                    if (e.candidate) {
                        localPC.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(`Error adding localPC iceCandidate: ${err}`);
                }
            };
            remotePC.onaddstream = e => {
                if (e.stream && remoteStream !== e.stream) {
                    setRemoteStream(e.stream);
                }
            };

            localPC.addStream(newStream);

            const offer = await localPC.createOffer();
            await localPC.setLocalDescription(offer);

            oUserService.patch(currentReceivedStreaming.current.uid, {
                streaming: Streaming.call(
                    currentReceivedStreaming.current,
                    user,
                    localPC.localDescription,
                ),
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        setCachedLocalPC(localPC);
        setCachedRemotePC(remotePC);
    };

    const answerCall = async (oUser, oCaller) => {
        try {
            let newStream = await startLocalStream();

            localPC = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
            remotePC = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

            localPC.onicecandidate = e => {
                try {
                    if (e.candidate) {
                        remotePC.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(`Error adding remotePC iceCandidate: ${err}`);
                }
            };
            remotePC.onicecandidate = e => {
                try {
                    if (e.candidate) {
                        localPC.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(`Error adding localPC iceCandidate: ${err}`);
                }
            };
            remotePC.onaddstream = e => {
                if (e.stream && remoteStream !== e.stream) {
                    setRemoteStream(e.stream);
                }
            };

            localPC.addStream(newStream);

            await remotePC.setRemoteDescription(oCaller.localDescription);

            let remoteStreams = remotePC.getRemoteStreams();
            remoteStreams.map(s => {
                console.log(s);
                setRemoteStream(s);
            });

            await localPC.setRemoteDescription(oCaller.localDescription);

            const offer = await localPC.createOffer();
            // const offer = await localPC.createAnswer();
            await localPC.setLocalDescription(offer);

            oUserService.patch(currentReceivedStreaming.current.uid, {
                streaming: Streaming.answer(
                    currentReceivedStreaming.current,
                    localPC.localDescription,
                ),
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        setCachedLocalPC(localPC);
        setCachedRemotePC(remotePC);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentReceivedStreaming.current.uid) {
            let current = currentReceivedStreaming.current;
            if (current.streaming) {
                if (
                    current.streaming.status === 'closed' ||
                    current.streaming.status === 'rejected'
                ) {
                    // Actions.popTo('dashboard');
                }
                if (current.streaming.status === 'pending') {
                    if (
                        current.streaming.users.receiver.uid ===
                        session.user.uid
                    ) {
                        answerCall(current, current.streaming.users.caller);
                    }
                }
                if (current.streaming.status === 'ongoing' && remotePC) {
                    if (
                        current.streaming.users.caller.uid === session.user.uid
                    ) {
                        remotePC.setRemoteDescription(
                            current.streaming.receiver.localDescription,
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, [currentReceivedStreaming.current]);

    const closeStreams = () => {
        try {
            if (cachedLocalPC) {
                cachedLocalPC.removeStream(localStream);
                cachedLocalPC.close();
            }
            if (cachedRemotePC) {
                cachedRemotePC.removeStream(remoteStream);
                cachedRemotePC.close();
            }

            setLocalStream();
            setRemoteStream();
            setCachedRemotePC();
            setCachedLocalPC();

            oUserService
                .patch(currentReceivedStreaming.current.uid, {
                    streaming: {
                        ...currentReceivedStreaming.current.streaming,
                        status: 'closed',
                    },
                })
                .then(() => Actions.popTo('dashboard'));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR', e);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!localStream && caller.uid === session.user.uid) {
            startCall();
        }
    }, [currentUserStore.current.streaming]);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            {/* {!localStream && (
                <Button
                    title="Click to start stream"
                    onPress={startLocalStream}
                />
            )} */}
            {/* {localStream && (
                <Button
                    title="Click to start call"
                    onPress={startCall}
                    disabled={!!remoteStream}
                />
            )} */}

            <View style={styles.rtcview}>
                {localStream && (
                    <RTCView
                        style={styles.rtc}
                        streamURL={localStream.toURL()}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
            <Text>{!!remoteStream && 'YES'}</Text>
            <View style={styles.rtcview}>
                {remoteStream && (
                    <RTCView
                        style={styles.rtc}
                        streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
            <Button title="Click to stop call" onPress={closeStreams} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#313131',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '100%',
        paddingVertical: 30,
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 30,
    },
    rtcview: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '40%',
        width: '80%',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    rtc: {
        width: '80%',
        height: '100%',
    },
});
```

Comment: The main webrtc samples are in javascript but they might be able to get you started https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, how does a video call between two browsers look like from a developer's point of view?

1. After all the preliminary preparation and creation of the necessary
   JavaScript objects on the first browser, the WebRTC method
   createOffer() is called, which returns a text packet in SDP format
   (or, in the future, a JSON serializable object if the oRTC version
   of the API picks up the "classical" one). This packet contains
   information about what kind of communication the developer wants:
   voice, video or send data, which codecs are there - this whole
   story.
2. And now - the signaling. The developer must somehow (really, it is written in the specification!) Pass this text packet offer to
   the second browser. For example, using your own server on the
   Internet and WebSocket connection from both browsers.
3. After receiving the offer on the second browser, the developer passes it to WebRTC using the setRemoteDescription()
   method. Then he calls the createAnswer() method, which returns the
   same text packet in SDP format, but for the second browser and
   taking into account the received packet from the first Browser.
4. Signaling continues: the developer passes the answer text packet back to the first Browser.
5. After receiving the answer on the first Browser, the developer passes it to WebRTC using the already mentioned
   setRemoteDescription() method, after which WebRTC in both browsers
   is minimally aware of each other. Can I connect? Unfortunately no.
   In fact, everything is just beginning...
6. WebRTC in both Browsers begins to analyze the status of the network connection (in fact, the standard does not indicate when to
   do this, and for many browsers WebRTC starts to study the network
   immediately after creating the corresponding objects, so as not to
   create unnecessary delays when connecting). When the developer in
   the first step was creating WebRTC objects, he should at least pass
   the address of the STUN server. This is a server that, in response
   to the UDP packet “what is my IP”, transmits the IP address from
   which this packet was received. WebRTC uses the STUN server to get
   an “external” IP address, compare it with an “internal” one and see
   if there is NAT. And if so, which reverse ports does NAT use to
   route UDP packets?
7. From time to time, WebRTC on both browsers will call the onicecandidate callback, transmitting the SIP packet with
   information for the second connection participant. This packet
   contains information about internal and external IP addresses,
   connection attempts, ports used by NAT, and so on. The developer
   uses signaling to transfer these packets between Browsers. The
   transmitted packet is sent to WebRTC using the addIceCandidate()
   method.
8. After a while, WebRTC will establish a peer-to-peer connection. Or will not be able if NAT will interfere. For such
   cases, the developer can transmit the address of the TURN server,
   which will be used as an external connecting element: both browsers
   will transmit UDP packets with voice or video through it. If the
   STUN server can be found for free (for example, google has it), then
   you will have to raise the TURN server yourself. Nobody is
   interested in passing terabytes of video traffic through themselves
   for free.

In conclusion: you will need in minimum STUN server, as maximum TURN server. Or both, if you do not know which kind of network configuration will be used by users.
You can read this [blog](https://bloggeek.me/) for more detailed information. I find it very informative.

Comment: I will recheck the step-by-step implemented by me to see if it fits on your descriptions. Thanks